# I need help interpreting the signature located in the upper right corner of my silk painting. Can anyone help?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, character-identification

**Can anyone interpret the signature located in the upper right-hand corner of my painting own silk fabric. I'm guessing that it dates to around the 1960s. I'm not sure whether or not the signature is Japanese or whether it might be Chinese**. I am curious to know any and all information concerning this artist.

- [image]
- [image]

Comment: The children drew it casually, and wrote a few strokes on it casually. Who knows what he wrote.